# Phonegap Android upload to remote database fails

Tags: php, android, mysql, cordova

Using phonegap / android I have successfully downloaded data from Db using jsonp from remote server (using localhost) Now trying to **upload** data using jquery/ajax.
Process appears to be working but no data being uploaded (ie data not appearing in MySql Db)
I'm using localhost as Db for test purposes.
Code::

```
**save.php**
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","sean") ;
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$sql="INSERT INTO contacts(id, cusname, custaddress)
VALUES
('$_POST[id]','$_POST[cusname]','$_POST[custaddress]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
        echo "Comment added";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>

**post.js**
$(document).bind('deviceready', function(){
    $(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(){

            var postData = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: postData,
                //change the url for your project
                url: 'http://localhost/post_to_server/save.php',
                success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert('Details successfully added');
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('There was an error adding details');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Also should this work in browser for testing purposes?

Comment: Are you testing this on a device or emulator?  Do you get any error messages in the console or in logcat? Also yes the code should work in a browser and you should be able to test it in a browser unless you are relying on cordova/phonegap functions, which won't be available in a regular desktop browser. If post.js and it's html page don't have any cordova/phonegap, then you should be able to test it in the desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

**My way of debugging:**

In the chrome developer console check on the response and request data of your ajax call. It will tell you what happens.

You will see the link (if ajax call is successful)

```
http://localhost/post_to_server/save.php
```

in the "Network" tab of the chrome developer console (even with FF). Click on that link and you can inspect whats posted to your script and what happens wrt database .

Once you identify whats posted in the ajax call, you can take it forward from there.